# If statement does not working in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Hey I am trying to make a if statement, which define the language which is been using in the website first, and then depends on the language, choosing the right content to show up.

Here is the code

```
[insert_php]$mylocale = get_bloginfo('language');if ($mylocale=="fr-FR"){[/insert_php]
        <div>Fr</div>[insert_php]}else{[/insert_php]
        <div>Eng</div>[insert_php] } [/insert_php]
```

WordPress does not allow PHP inside pages or posts, so I use a plugin called "insert PHP" to test the code inside a page, therefore I am using `[insert_php]` instead of `<?php ?>`. 
But the problem is the if statement does not work. it always shows both of "Eng" and "Fr" without picking the right one.

I also tried

```
[insert_php]$mylocale = get_bloginfo('language');if($mylocale=="fr-FR"):[/insert_php]
<div>Fr</div>[insert_php]; else:[/insert_php]
<div>Eng</div>[insert_php]; endif;[/insert_php]
```

Does not work as well.

Anyone can help me please? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried doing an `echo` and just wrapping the entire statement in a single set of shortcodes?

Comment: @mevius yes i did use echo to test if no breaks between the entire statement, and that works fine, it only picks the right one I want. but i need the <div> stuffs because I will need to put more things on it

Comment: Are you sure that plugin's evening running? does `[insert_php]echo 'hello world';[/insert_php]` do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the nature of the plugin, you're going to have to wrap the entire statement in the shortcode tags:

```
[insert_php]
    $mylocale = get_bloginfo('language');
    if ($mylocale=="fr-FR") {
        echo '<div>Fr</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div>Eng</div>';
    } 
[/insert_php]
```

However, [from the docs](http://www.willmaster.com/software/WPplugins/insert-php-wordpress-plugin-instructions.php) , you should be aware of the following:

> The code between [insert_php] and [/insert_php] must be complete in
>   and of itself. The block of code is fed into the eval() function,
>   where the PHP code is run.
>
> References to variables, functions, or code blocks outside the area
>   between [insert_php] and [/insert_php] will fail because the code
>   being eval()'d has no access to the outside. In other words, no
>   outside scope is possible.

It's likely you won't have access to `get_bloginfo()` because it is outside of the scope, rendering all of this impossible.

Comment: I cannot believe I forgot this way... thanks so much :-)